# The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FirebaseOptions?'

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio

Hello I am trying to implement firebase authentication in my flutter app I am getting this error  'Undefined name 'DefaultFirebaseOptions'.'

Sample source code from firebase page:Get to know Firebase for Flutter

Here is the code for reference:

```
   import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
   import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
   import 'firebase_options.dart';//not adding in my project?
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
   import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
   import 'src/authentication.dart';
   import 'src/widgets.dart';

class ApplicationState extends ChangeNotifier {
  ApplicationState() {
    init();
  }

 


    Future<void> init() async {

    await Firebase.initializeApp(

      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );

    FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        _loginState = ApplicationLoginState.loggedIn;
      } else {
        _loginState = ApplicationLoginState.loggedOut;
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set it such way,

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: "//your API key",
        authDomain: "//your auth domain",
        projectId: "//project id",
        storageBucket: "///storage",
        messagingSenderId: "//message sender id",
        appId: "// app id",
        measurementId: "// measurementId"
    )
      );
);
```

All these data can be found from firebase console -> your project -> Added Apps -> Gear Icon (settings) -> scroll down to find `SDK setup and configuration`
.

you'll find these info there

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

All other data is available in googleservices.json file